# Which attribute should i use to findElement in the below hyperlink?

Tags: selenium

Tried using

```
By.id("aaabICLL.AreaViewStatic.ServiceLink17"), By.className("urLnkFunction"),Xpath, linkText("Serviceman Basic Report")
```

And for these encountered this error:

```
NoSuchElementException.eclipse is unable to locate the "Serviceman Basic Report" hyperlink.
```

Serviceman Basic Report

Comment: wheres the HTML ?

Comment: Webportal....using Chrome browser

Comment: can you paste the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following xpath for your case:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Serviceman Basic Report')]")).click();
```

Hope it will help you.